# Accessing Min/Max key from SortedDictionary in O(1)

Tags: c#, .net, performance, sorteddictionary

I have a (large) [`SortedDictionary<TKey,TValue>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.sorteddictionary-2) and I need to access the min/max keys efficiently, presumably in O(1) time since the keys are "sorted".

How do I do this?

Comment: I remember needing this and finding various indications that the solution is “build your own `SortedDictionary` out of `SortedSet`” (`SortedSet` has `Min` and `Max`). [Relevant issue comment about the last progress on the issue](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/18668#issuecomment-954969981), which is wrong, of course.

Comment: @Ry- Yeah, I've been rewriting a lot of the core library these days. Yet another useless class that needs to be replaced. I will use a BTree perhaps.

Comment: You could consider using the `TreeDictionary<K,V>` class from the [C5](https://github.com/sestoft/C5) library, which is a sorted generic dictionary based on a red-black tree set. It has `FindMin`/`FindMax` methods.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias Excellent to know, thanks.